# Angular with Jasmine--route param isn't subscribed after route change in test function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

After triggering a route change, `Location.path()` tells me that it's in the new route, but `ngOnInit` (in component) can't subscribe to the route param.

my html:

```
<li>
  <a id="categoryButton{{category}}" 
     role="button" 
     style="color: white;background-color: #107C10;" 
     class="c-button f-primary" 
     [routerLink]="['/blog/category', category]">
     {{category}}
  </a>
</li>
```

my test function:

```
it('when click on category link, route changes', async(inject([ Location], (location: Location) => {
    component.isLoading = false;
    const categoryTag = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#categoryButtonUpdates'));
    categoryTag.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 } );
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toEqual('/blog/category/Updates');
        expect(component.route.params).toBeDefined();
        expect(component.category).toBe('Updates');
    });
})));
```

`ngOnInit()` in my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.testing = "works";
  this.getFeaturedBlogPost();
  this.route.params.subscribe(
     params => {
      this.category = params['category'];
      if (!this.category) {
        this.getBlogPost();
      } else {
        this.getBlogPostByCategory(this.category);
      }
  });
}
```

it seems like `component.category` can't grab the category value from `params['category']` so it stays as `undefined`. What am i missing? How do I make the component to recognize the param change?